# How to increase the efficiency when you have 1000x1000 matrix in Excel?

Tags: excel, optimization, matrix

Using [OpenSolver](http://opensolver.org/), I'm trying to solve a basic [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) for problem size of 1000.

So excel file has a matrix of 1000x1000. Each value inside the matrix can be either 0 or 1.

Solving a sample problem takes over 10 hours to complete and there are +100 samples. But I have one week the finish the whole thing.

I suspect the main reason of the inefficiency is caused by the matrix and how Excel handles it.

Is there any way to speed up the process? Any ideas?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: hard to say without something to see or test, would turning off auto calculation help?

Comment: Use a programming language C, C++ or Javato implement the algorithm you want, that would be way faster.

Comment: I agree with WhiteHat, very difficult to make an informed suggestion without more information. What scripts are you using? When you mention matrix does that mean values in cells? If it is consider using variables instead to store your matrix as the read write operations into cells take considerable more processing power than storing it in a variable. But more details would be better.

Comment: Are you forcing the variables to be 0 or 1? In the standard assignment problem, you can use real decision variables to be constrained to be between 0 and 1 and just use the simplex algorithm and, in the optimal solution they will be 0 or 1 after all. With 10 hours of CPU time it sounds like you are doing branch-and-bound. Also, if time really is an issue, perhaps you can use the Hungarian algorithm. Implementing it in pure VBA will probably give you run times two orders of magnitude better than 10 hours.

Comment: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` might help.

Comment: Show your code please. Are you manipulating cells directly, or loading the matrix in memory for fast operation? What solver are you using?

Comment: It shouldn't take that long.  As a test, I created a sample problem of the same size and type and solved it OpenSolver.  It took about 10 minutes on my somewhat modest laptop.  Have you set up the problem correctly in OpenSolver?  Does your spreadsheet do any complex calculations beyond the required summing up of variables by rows and columns (to enforce the 1:1 assignment constraint) and products of variables and coefficients (to calculate the objective).

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this is probably due to time of getting data in and out of Excel. The solution time for an assignment problem of this size should be a few minutes at most. See [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2015/12/1000-x-1000-assignment-problem-10-hours.html) for some timings. The problem is not very small: 1000 x 1000 means 2k equations and 1e6 variables. However an assignment problem has a simple structure and solves very quickly. It seems you want to run several data sets in a row, so this is more of a batch operation than an interactive task.

A simple approach would be to write a little bit of code that generates an LP file for a data set and then feed it in a solver (a public domain solver will do, e.g. CBC, GLPK). Then create a batch file that runs through all the data sets.

Answer (score 1):

If you like OpenSolver and want to stick with it, try the QuickSolve Option. It may or may not apply to you depending on what changes in the subsequent 100 optimizations. OpenSolver is usually slow setting up the problem, but if most of the 10 hours are spent initializing the model may be the rest of the 100 optimizations can be solved in a few minutes. You can even get VBA do this for you.
Or you can take a step up and try SolverStudio.

Answer (score 0):

Do these 1000 x 1000 cells consist of links and references.  Or do you have a script writing these 1s and 0s?  The Workbook will slow to crawling speed if you are refreshing 1000 x 1000 links.  Please do a copy > paste special > values, if you can, so the Workbook is not constantly updating.

Also, see this.

http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/ten-things-you-can-do-to-speed-up-your-excel-vba-code/

Answer (score 0):

A matrix of 1000x1000. Each value inside the matrix can be either 0 or 1.

The solution is a mathematical one. Try to find some block diagonal structure and diagonalize each block. This is a very hard problem.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BlockDiagonalMatrix.html

Comment: Assignment problems are actually not very hard. Problems of this size solve in less than a few minutes.